# How can I access Spring properties defined in app.properties from Mule FuncionalTestCase?

Tags: mule

How can I access Spring properties defined in app.properties from Mule FuncionalTestCase?

For example, in my production config I have a ${sessionExpiresInSecondsValue} passed in to a bean property. What I want to do is get this value and use it with the FunctionalTestComponent to wait for the same amount of time as that value and I don't want to harcode so the test go out of sync with the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to get this bean that receives `${sessionExpiresInSecondsValue}` from the registry, via `MuleContext`, and call `getSessionExpiresInSecondsValue()` on it.